Rename URLfails
Maybe a stupid question, but anyway. I built up a whole new Wordpress website (not yet online) and had to try around a little bit. Choosing the URL of choice was fine for all but one page. Its name should be ….de/test/, but whenever I save this, WP changes this to …./test-3/. Can you help me getting rid of the number at the end? Thanks.
Tried and tried in vain. Looked up Google, but that was too technical

This is not a general software help site. You're better off at looking at some wordpress specific forums!

It’s likely that a similar page or post in WordPress is causing it to automatically append a number to your URL.
Check for Existing Slugs:

Go to your WordPress dashboard.
Navigate to Pages or Posts (depending on where you’re seeing the issue).
Look for any pages or posts with a similar slug (e.g., test). If you find any, either change their slugs or delete them if they’re no longer needed.


The URL slug (the part after the last slash) you want to use might be already in use by another page, post, or some other content type in WordPress, even if it's in the trash.

Yes, that’s what I had thought. But the trash is empty, and no other pages going by the name of /test/ around …

Found the culprit. In fact, there were two images (!) in the media section named test, which caused the problem! So I could solve it. Thanks everybody
